# How to convert a `NonEmptyList[Either[Error, User]]` to `Either[Error, NonEmptyList[User]]` with cats?

Tags: scala, list, scala-cats, either

I'm using [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/), wonder how to turn a data with it:

```
val data = NonEmptyList[Either[Error, User]]
```

to

```
val target: Either[Error, NonEmptyList[User]] = howToConvert(data)
```

Comment: I think your task is underspecified. What if you had several errors? How they should be aggregated into a single error? Moreover if you have some non-failed `User`s and some `Error`s, what you expect to get? Some `Error` or the list of successful `User`s?

Comment: @SergGr Thanks for your questions. If there are several errors, I just want the final result to have the first one

Comment: And if there are both `Error`s and valid `User`s?

Comment: @SergGr, then it will be a `Left(error)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when you want to turn the type constructors inside out you are probably looking for `sequence`. If you have `-Ypartial-unification` turned on in Scala >= 2.11.9 you can just let the compiler infer everything:

```
data.sequence
```

Otherwise:

```
type EitherError[A] = Either[Error, A]
data.sequence[EitherError, User]
```

Or if you have the [type lambda plugin](https://github.com/non/kind-projector):

```
data.sequence[Either[Error, ?], User]
```

Or if you don't have the plugin, but you dislike type aliases:

```
data.sequence[({type L[A] = Either[Error, A]})#L, User]
```

It will do the expected thing of either returning the first error, or all users if there is no error. If we pretend users are ints and errors are strings:

```
scala> import cats.data.NonEmptyList, cats.implicits._
import cats.data.NonEmptyList
import cats.implicits._

scala> val data: NonEmptyList[Either[Error, User]] = NonEmptyList.of(Right(2), Left("error1"), Right(4))
data: cats.data.NonEmptyList[Either[Error,User]] = NonEmptyList(Right(2), Left(error1), Right(4))

scala> data.sequence
res4: Either[Error,cats.data.NonEmptyList[User]] = Left(error1)
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I finally choose the first way, and thanks for showing me another two ways

Comment: Jasper, good job in psychic reading of the real question - 100% hit.